How come my model in tensorflow.js is not predicting correctly but in python it is? [Resnet-50 Transfer Learning]
I have checked with about 20 images. The same ones for python, and the same ones with tensorflow.js with extremely similar preprocessing. It keeps giving me the 0th class.
Here is my python training code:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np

tf.random.set_seed(123)

img_height, img_width = 224, 224
batch_size = 32
data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/AI2/Processed'

# random horizontal flips, random rotation, color jitter, normalize
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.2),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomContrast(0.2),
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomTranslation(height_factor=(-0.1, 0.1), width_factor=(-0.1, 0.1)),
])

def one_hot_encode(image, label):
    label = tf.one_hot(label, 5)
    return image, label

def main():
    train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="training",
        seed=123,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    )

    val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="validation",
        seed=123,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    )

    class_names = train_ds.class_names
    print(class_names)

    class_count = [0] * len(class_names)
    for images, labels in train_ds.unbatch().as_numpy_iterator():
        class_count[int(labels)] += 1


    train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (data_augmentation(x, training=True), y))
    train_ds = train_ds.map(one_hot_encode).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    val_ds = val_ds.map(one_hot_encode).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


    base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet',
        input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)
    )

    # Freeze all layers in the base model
    base_model.trainable = False



    # Create the model architecture
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3))
    x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation='softmax')(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

    # Freeze all layers except the last one
    # for layer in model.layers[:-1]:
    #     layer.trainable = False

    # Unfreeze the last layer in the model
    model.layers[-1].trainable = True

    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Train the model
    class_weights = {i: 1. / count for i, count in enumerate(class_count)}
    history = model.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        epochs=10,
        class_weight=class_weights
    )

    # Evaluate on validation set
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(val_ds)
    print(f"Validation accuracy: {accuracy * 100}%")

    # Print the model summary
    model.summary()

    model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/AI2/sampleModel.h5')

I then do this:
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras /Users/hb/Desktop/tfModel3/sampleModel.h5 /Users/hb/Desktop/tfModel3/sampleModelNew

Here is my Python code for predicting:
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/AI2/sampleModel.h5')

    # Show the model architecture
    model.summary()

    img_height = 224
    img_width = 224

    # Load the image
    img_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/AI2/RealTest/bmw.jpg'  # replace with your image path
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)

    # Preprocess the image using the same preprocessing function used for ImageNet
    img_array = preprocess_input(img_array)

    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

    # Make a prediction
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    predicted_class = np.argmax(predictions[0])

    # Print the class name
    print('Predicted class:', predicted_class)

And after all that, I have my React code using tensorflowjs which gives me no errors on every image I provide it. The model imports successfully! It gives a prediction without errors. But its the wrong prediction every single time!:
  const { state, dispatch } = useMyContext(); // Use the custom hook to access state and dispatch
  const [model, setModel] = React.useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadModel() {
      const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('/models/model.json');
      setModel(model);
      console.log('model loaded')
      console.log('model', model);

      

      model.summary();
    }

    loadModel()
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!state.imageFiles) return;
    if (state.imageFiles.length === 0) return;


    
  
    const newImgFunc = async () => {
      const img = new Image();
      const imageFile = state.imageFiles[0];
      img.src = await URL.createObjectURL(imageFile);
      img.onload = async () => {
        const class_names = ['Audi_A3_2021_Processed', 'BMW_1-Series_2016_Processed', 'Ford_Puma_2021_Processed', 'Nissan_Juke_2023_Processed', 'Nissan_Qashqai_2021_Processed'];
    
        // Match preprocess_input from Keras for ResNet50
        const mean = tf.tensor1d([123.68, 116.779, 103.939]);
        const std = tf.tensor1d([58.393, 57.12, 57.375]); // This line can be removed if not used
    
        let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img)
          .resizeBilinear([224, 224]) // Using bilinear, as its typically more accurate
          .toFloat()
          .sub(mean) // Subtract mean
          .div(tf.scalar(255)); // Scale to [0,1]
    
        const prediction = await model.predict(tensor.expandDims());
        const predictions = prediction.dataSync();
        const predictedClassIndex = predictions.indexOf(Math.max(...predictions));
        console.log('Predicted Class:', class_names[predictedClassIndex]);
      };
    }
    
    newImgFunc();
  }, [state]);
    const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles: any[]) => {
      acceptedFiles.forEach((file: Blob) => {
        const reader = new FileReader()
  
        reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted')
        reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed')
        reader.onload = () => {
          const binaryStr = reader.result
          console.log(binaryStr)

          const file = new File(
            [binaryStr as BlobPart],
            'imageName'
           
          );

          dispatch({ type: 'SET_IMAGE_FILES', payload: [file] });
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
      })
      
    }, [])

